# What's the difference between a full and final settlement and either merely a full or merely a final settlement?

Tags: legal-terms, settlement

Perhaps the phrase was designed to mitigate caveats of either one or another... What would these have been?

And secondly, realistically, would a court ever uphold the difference between a settlement described in one of these terms but not both?

Comment: It is a literary device that can be read as "fully (completely) final." See [A challenge to hendiadys in the law](https://reason.com/volokh/2020/12/01/a-challenge-to-hendiadys-in-the-law/) (2020).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A “full and final settlement” is a complete resolution of all matters in dispute between the parties.

This can be contrasted with both a partial settlement, which resolves some but not all issues, and an interim settlement, which means something still remains to be done.

A partial settlement probably needs no further explanation - some things are dealt with and some things aren’t.

An interim settlement an be almost anything:

- an agreement pending the outcome of a further process: negotiation, arbitration, litigation, whatever.
- a payment on account because a final payment cannot yet be determined, similar to interim and final dividends from a company.
- an interim award from an arbitration or judicial process.
- a payment by instalments.
- anything else you can think of.